# context.Database.Migrate(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I cloned https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers and try to run some tests. The following method called by the test case raise the exceptions

```
    private static void InvokeSeeder<TContext>(Action<TContext, IServiceProvider> seeder, TContext context, IServiceProvider services)
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        context.Database.Migrate(); // Error
        seeder(context, services);
    }
```

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.c__DisplayClass12_0`2.b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostExtensions.InvokeSeeder[TContext](Action`2 seeder, TContext context, IServiceProvider services) in D:\ck\Documents\GitHub\eShopOnContainers\src\BuildingBlocks\WebHostCustomization\WebHost.Customization\WebHostExtensions.cs:line 75
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostExtensions.c__DisplayClass1_1`1.b__2() in D:\ck\Documents\GitHub\eShopOnContainers\src\BuildingBlocks\WebHostCustomization\WebHost.Customization\WebHostExtensions.cs:line 54
   at Polly.Policy.c__DisplayClass108_0.b__0(Context ctx, CancellationToken ct)
   at Polly.Policy.c__DisplayClass138_0.b__0(Context ctx, CancellationToken token)
   at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.Implementation[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Action`4 onRetry, Int32 permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4 sleepDurationProvider)

Inner Exception 1:
Win32Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

The `CatalogContext` source code can be found at https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Infrastructure/CatalogContext.cs

Comment: Did you install SQL server and configure the connection string?

Answer (score 2):

You if cloned their repo, and didn't change the configuration. this is the connection string your database will be trying to connect to :

`"Server=.;Initial Catalog=Microsoft.eShopOnContainers.Services.CatalogDb;Integrated Security=true"`

`Server=.` - it means that you will have to install the SQL Server on your machine (not SQLEXPRESS not mssqllocaldb)

and `Integrated Security=true` - means that you will have to configure the db so that your current windows account credentials are used for the authentication.

Either you set the SQL Server on your machine that way, or adjust the connection string

Comment: Note that this connection string will work with SQL Server Express edition, you'd just have to enable TCP/IP and configure it to listen on port 1433 like a default instance.